# import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (5:2)

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I am getting this error: import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (5:2)
All the other stackoverflow related pages dont give me the right answer. I am React.js beginner and dont know where the mistake is coming frome.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

 function myFunction() {

  export const ePosDevice = useRef();
  export const printer = useRef();



    let ePosDev = new window.epson.ePOSDevice();
    ePosDevice.current = ePosDev;

    ePosDev.connect("192.168.1.254", 8008, (data) => {
      if (data === "OK") {
        ePosDev.createDevice(
          "local_printer",
          ePosDev.DEVICE_TYPE_PRINTER,
          { crypto: true, buffer: false },
          (devobj, retcode) => {
            if (retcode === "OK") {
              printer.current = devobj;
            } else {
              throw retcode;
            }
          }
        );
      } else {
        throw data;
      }
    });
  
}

export { myFunction };
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You can't export something from within a function. Imports and exports cannot be nested within another block, they need to be at the top level.

Comment: @HenryWoody Is it possible to work with a custom hook? Vinyl answerded this below, can you help me to do this? Please

Comment: If you want to turn this function into a custom hook, you just need to rename it so its name starts with `use` (e.g. `useMyCustomHook`), then just export it normally (like `export function useMyCustomHook() { ... }` and then you can import it into other files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
export default myFunction;
import myFunction from 'your_module'
```

or if you want to named export:

```
export const myFunction,
 import { myFunction } from 'your_module'
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: Thanks! I have Problems with the useRef(): React Hook "useRef" is called in function "myFunction" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: As I already said I am beginner, and this is the error which makes me a little bid sad, because after 5 hours i cant solve this.

Comment: If you want to export variable that inside the function, you can write custom hook.

Comment: Can you please help me to do this? I know this is not very dificult for a developer,  but for me as a beginner it is. I asked some other people, but they dont want to help me. Furthermore I need this code, I wanted to present it my Friends later...

Comment: So that I can understand how to deal with this special situation.